# ThreadPoolExecutor javadoc, three strategies for queuing and lockups

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

In Oracle documentation for ThreadPoolExecutor class it is written:

> There are three general strategies for queuing:
>
> **Direct handoffs.** A good default choice for a work queue is a SynchronousQueue that hands
> off tasks to threads without otherwise holding them. Here, an attempt
> to queue a task will fail if no threads are immediately available to
> run it, so a new thread will be constructed. **This policy avoids
> lockups when handling sets of requests that might have internal
> dependencies.** Direct handoffs generally require unbounded
> maximumPoolSizes to avoid rejection of new submitted tasks. This in
> turn admits the possibility of unbounded thread growth when commands
> continue to arrive on average faster than they can be processed.
>
> **Unbounded queues.** Using an unbounded queue (for example a LinkedBlockingQueue without a predefined capacity) will cause new
> tasks to wait in the queue when all corePoolSize threads are busy.
> Thus, no more than corePoolSize threads will ever be created. (And the
> value of the maximumPoolSize therefore doesn't have any effect.) **This
> may be appropriate when each task is completely independent of others,
> so tasks cannot affect each others execution;** for example, in a web
> page server. While this style of queuing can be useful in smoothing
> out transient bursts of requests, it admits the possibility of
> unbounded work queue growth when commands continue to arrive on
> average faster than they can be processed.
> ...

Why direct handoff strategy is better at avoiding lockups in comparison to unbounded queues strategy? Or do I understand it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a `corePoolSize = 1`. If the first task submits another task to the same pool and wait for the results it will lock up indefinitely.

However if a task is completley independent there would be no reason to use direct handoff in regards to preventing lockups.

This is just an example, `internal dependency` can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, as I see, there are plenty of possibilities for a lockup with direct handoff. OK, I'll assume that's some 'figure of speech' by Oracle Devs and there is not much in it.

Comment: @vziminov The difference is that if the pool is completley filled with locked tasks (corePoolSize) it will never be able to receive more tasks. It all depends on your use case. Generally I wouldn't want too many concurrent threads to run if they're cpu bound so `Unbounded queues` would be my choice if possible